# BigQuery - Return Weekday Value from date obj

Tags: google-bigquery

trying to get the weekday ie "sunday" from a datetime obj in big query using the below:

```
EXTRACT(WEEK (<WEEKDAY>) FROM closed_at)
```

but no luck https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#extract

I get error:

```
Syntax error: Expected ")" but got "<" at [10:15]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below as an example

```
SELECT EXTRACT(WEEK (MONDAY) FROM closed_at)
```